# symbol lookup error: ldapdelete: undefined symbol: ldap_pvt_conf_option

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

I'am trying to delete an entry from my LDAP database and it works fine, but for some reason after Linux update I am getting the below error;

```
symbol lookup error: ldapdelete: undefined symbol:
ldap_pvt_conf_option
```

There is my `ldapdelete` command:

```
ldapdelete -D "cn=adm,dc=ng,dc=com" -w root -x -r -v "cn=adm,ou=Customers,ou=People,o=NG,dc=ng,dc=com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You installation seems broken. The command-line tool *ldapdelete* uses a library which was probably not properly updated.

Look for strange errors happening during dynamic linking:

`ldd $(which ldapdelete)`

And check which package provides *ldapdelete*:

`rpm -qf $(which ldapdelete)`